# Eclipse: Getting error when adding external class / jar files to build path: "XYZ Cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, .class-file

I am working with Java and Eclipse, which are both a bit out of my comfort zone (yup , this is an assignment...).

I have 2 `class` files which I need to use in my project. So far I have tried:

### Attempt #1

I tried adding an `external class folder`:

1. In my project folder I have added `classes\legacy` folder.
2. In `Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries` I Clicked on the `Add External Class Folder`
3. In the window that opened I selected the `classes` folder created in step 1.
4. In my code I have added `import legacy.*;`

**Result:**
I can use the classes in the `class` files but getting the following errors:
(seems to occur when the classes are attempting to use one another)

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot
>   find the class file for IshKesher. Fix the build path then try
>   building this project
>
> The type IshKesher cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

**Note:** tried for `class folder` as well - same results.

[image]

### Attempt #2

Someone suggested that using jar files should be easier, so I gave it a try:

1. Created a `jar` file containing the `class` files: `jar cvf classes.jar ContactsList.class IshKesher.class`
2. Added the `jar` file to the build path using [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)) tutorial.

**Result:**
Getting an error for each usage of classes in the jar file:

> XYZ Cannot be resolved to a type

[image]

Any Ideas how make the class files available in my code?

---

**EDIT:**
It turned out that `Attempt #2` worked once using my source files in the `default package` (cannot figure out why though...).

Comment: For `case 2` you have to import the classes.. `import legacy.*`

Comment: @GoldRoger Thanks, Tried that already. I'm getting  `The import legacy cannot be resolved`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try my instructions.

If you don't want to include copy of Borat.jar, but only want to reference it from an external folder, then just do this one step -

No copy step -

```
Your java project > Right click > Build path > Configure 
build path > add EXTERNAL jars button > select your jar 
> ok.
```

If you want that jar to become a part of your java app, ie create a copy of the jar in your java app, then use the steps below.

**Step 1- Create a lib folder in your app to store all jars**

```
Your java project > Right click > New Folder > Folder Name = lib
```

**Step 2 - Import all copies of the necessary jars into lib folder**

```
Your java project > lib folder > Right click > import > General --> 
File System > From Directory = The directory where you stored your jar files.
> ...You should now see the jars in that folder. Lets say we want to import 
Borat.jar > Finish.
```

**Step 3 - To check if step 2 is done correctly**

```
Your java project > lib folder > Expand the lib folder to see its 
contents. Borat.jar should be listed there. Nice !
```

**Step 4 - Finally, to add the jars to the project**

```
Your java project > lib folder > Right click > Build path > Configure 
build path > add jars button > expand your project > expand lib folder
> Select Borat.jar > ok.
```

Comment: Yakshemash to you as well... I have tried your suggestions as part of **Attempt #2**. it is specified in the [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29)...

Comment: Your solution worked for me after moving my source files to the `default package`. There wasn't enough information in my question for you to guess that that was not the case, so I will accept this answer  as it is correct and will serve future googlers...